# How do I handle angularjs attributes in a component?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I am learning how to handle forms with angularjs. As far as I have understood, it is reasonable to create a component to handle custom input elements. Please do correct me if it is not a good practice.

Without using a component an input element like:

```
<input type="text" name="field" data-ng-model="myField" required />
```

can be validated via a model binding and the boolean method:

```
myField.$valid
```

Now, if I define a component using the following code:

```
{
myModel: '<',
template: '<input type="text" name="field" data-ng-model="$ctrl.myModel" required />'
}
```

why a call like:

```
$ctrl.myModel.$valid
```

is not parsed?
Which logic step am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
[formName].[inputFieldName].$valid
```

I think for this you need to give the name reference for validation.

Comment: I was using the same string to name and and ng-model attributes. That's why I thought I could access that property via angularjs.
Now, my question would be: is it possible to handle the validation identifying the element via the ng-model?